# How do I achieve this razor concept (partial views) in Metro/Rt?

Tags: razor, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I'm pretty new to Wpf/Metro/RT (I've done some stuff, but not much), and I'm trying to achieve this effect where I can pass an object to page/partial view to have it render on the main page, and potentially have it render recursively based on the content of the object that was passed. I apologize, it's pretty textbook, I'm just having a hard time explaining it so here's an example of how I might approach this in razor:

```
<!-- Parent View -->
@model MyProject.Thread
<div class="thread">
    <div class="comment-block">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class="label"})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class="label"})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body, new { @class="label"})
    </div>
    <div class="indent-replies">
        @for(var comment in Model.Comments)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_CommentPartial", comment)
        }
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Partial View -->
@model MyProject.Comment
<div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author, new { @class="label"})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment, new { @class="label"})
    </div>
    <div class="indent-replies">    
        @for(var comment in Model.Comments)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_CommentPartial", comment)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

So what's happening here? Think Reddit. It starts with a thread and the thread has comments. And each comment can have a reply, and each reply can have a reply, and so on forever and ever; that's the recursion I'm speaking of.

I'm thinking that I might be in need of creating a user control, but at first glance, I'm not seeing how it would be achieved. I feel like I would need to create a custom datasource with that user control but I don't know. So my question is this:

How do I achieve this effect in Metro/RT?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve something similar combining a `UserControl` with some `ItemsControls`.

Here is the model I've used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TreeViewSample
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Comments = new[]
            {
                new Comment
                {
                    Text = "root comment #1",
                    Comments = new[]
                    {
                        new Comment
                        {
                            Text = "comment #1 #1",
                            Comments = new[]
                            {
                                new Comment
                                {
                                    Text = "comment #1 #1 #1"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Comment
                        {
                            Text = "comment #1 #2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Comment
                {
                    Text = "root comment #2",
                    Comments = new[]
                    {
                        new Comment
                        {
                            Text = "comment #2 #1",
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `UserControl`:

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TreeViewSample.CommentView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TreeViewSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="root" Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Upload" IsCompact="True"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Download" IsCompact="True"></AppBarButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Comment.Text}"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Comment.Comments}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CommentView Comment="{Binding}"></local:CommentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TreeViewSample
{
    public sealed partial class CommentView : UserControl
    {
        public Comment Comment
        {
            get { return (Comment)GetValue(CommentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Comment", typeof(Comment), typeof(CommentView), new PropertyMetadata(null));        

        public CommentView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            root.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main page:

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TreeViewSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TreeViewSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,100,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CommentView Comment="{Binding}"></local:CommentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you reuse this kind of view many times you could share this `DataTemplate` or define a dedicated "CommentsView" `UserControl` too.

Code behind:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TreeViewSample
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Awesome!]

Note that there is a `TreeView` implementation in the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) (you can install it directly from **Visual Studio** with **NuGet**)